# Get First 2 Characters In a String

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to get first 2 characters in a string. Here's my code:

```
$s = 'hello'; // line 4
printf("[%0.2s]\n", %s); // line 5: Gets first 2 characters [he]
```

It's giving me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in
>   C:\laragon\www\karakter_tamamlama.php on line 5

Why am I getting error?

Comment: Hello, I'm not asking how to get first 2 chars. I'm asking why I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second arg should be `$s`, see [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf("[%0.2s]\n", $s);
```

Comment: Thanks your for the answers. How stupid of me!

Answer (score 5):

Use `substring` function to get letters from string.

An example:

```
substr($s, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

$s instead of %s

```
printf("[%0.2s]\n", $s);
```

or

```
substr($s, 0,2);
```